# Mysql complicated Inner join scenario

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

The table contains employees and the clients they worked for.

| employee | client |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 3 |

I need to find a employee who worked only for one client which is particularity client=2
therefore result should be "b,2", because "b"  and "d" are only employees who worked for one client but "b" should be expected because he worked for client=2 and "d" not

**expected Result:**

| employee | client |
| --- | --- |
| b | 2 |

Result should not contain "c" , as "c" worked for client=2 but also for another client=1

I tried following query , it returns all employee who worked only for one client(any of all ) but not sure how to impose client should be "2"

```
SELECT COUNT(*),employee FROM employee_client GROUP BY emplyoee HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT employee, MAX(client) client 
FROM employee_client 
GROUP BY employee 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND SUM(client <> 2) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b64014e98f69444c51d325d714dfe38).

Comment: Thank you so much forpas, It worked ..  out of Curiosity , whats if replace "SUM(client <> 2) = 0;" with "client=2"  ---> 

  SELECT employee, MAX(client) client 
FROM employee_client 
GROUP BY employee 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND client = 2; 

and why Max(client), why not only "client"

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND SUM(client = 2) = 0;` will return all employees which work for only 1 client but this client is not client 2.

Comment: isnt HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND client = 2; is the same as  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND SUM(client <> 2) = 0

Comment: @IjazAhmed now I saw the edited comment. `AND client = 2` is not valid in the HAVING clause, although MySql allows it, because a HAVING clause should contain aggregated expressions only. As I said MySql allows it and it works the same way (just because there is only 1 client), but it is not standard SQL.